# Add direction on the middle of a curve

Tags: java, draw

I'm using QuadCurve2D to draw curves  between my nodes

```
QuadCurve2D curve = new QuadCurve2D.Double(start.getX(), start.getY(), c1, c2, end.getX(), end.getY());
```

I used the following code to add a direction to the curve, where `g2d` is `Graphics2D` object

```
g2d.draw(curve);

Polygon arrowHead = new Polygon();
arrowHead.addPoint(0, 5);
arrowHead.addPoint(-5, -5);
arrowHead.addPoint(5, -5);

AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.setToIdentity();
double angle = Math.atan2(curve.getY2() - curve.getY1(), curve.getX2() - curve.getX1());
at.translate(curve.getX2(), curve.getY2());
at.rotate((angle - Math.PI / 2d));

g2d.setTransform(at);
g2d.fill(arrowHead);
```

I want to show the direction on the middle of the curve not at the end, I've tried changing the `.translate()` parameters but it appears in strange places. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First I iterated the path to get its length then I got the points at the center and drew my direction

```
PathIterator iterator = curve.getPathIterator(null, 1);
int count = 0;
double[] coordinates = new double[2];
while (!iterator.isDone()) {
    ++count;
    iterator.next();
}

iterator = curve.getPathIterator(null, 1);
int a = count / 2;
int b = a + 1;
count = 0;
while (!iterator.isDone()) {
    count++;
    iterator.currentSegment(coordinates);
    if (count == a) {
        x1 = (int) coordinates[0];
        y1 = (int) coordinates[1];
    } else if (count == b) {
        x2 = (int) coordinates[0];
        y2 = (int) coordinates[1];
    }
    iterator.next();
}
```

and my direction became

```
Polygon arrowHead = new Polygon();
arrowHead.addPoint(0, 5);
arrowHead.addPoint(-5, -5);
arrowHead.addPoint(5, -5);

AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.setToIdentity();
double angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
at.translate(x2, y2);
at.rotate((angle - Math.PI / 2d));
```